# Error in accessing textbox.text from web form to class library in same solution

Tags: c#, .net

class library code:

this code adds row to batch in BlackBaud Crm .
it s using the textbox and combobox from web form design.
Even in exception part it is giving error on BatchException

```
    public string AddRowToBatch(string param)
    {

        Guid SaveRequestGUID = default(Guid);
        Dictionary<string, string> BatchRowValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        int ISORGANIZATION = 0;
        string type = "Individual";
        try{
        if (type == "Individual")
        {
            ISORGANIZATION = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ISORGANIZATION = 1;
        }

        BatchRowValues.Add(this.comboBox1.Tag.ToString, ISORGANIZATION.ToString);
        BatchRowValues.Add(this.textBox2.Tag.ToString, this.textBox2.Text.ToString);//key name 
        BatchRowValues.Add(this.comboBox2.Tag.ToString, ((SimpleAddressType)this.comboBox2.SelectedItem).AddressType.ToString);//address type
        BatchRowValues.Add(this.textBox3.Tag.ToString, this.textBox3.Text.ToString);//address
        BatchRowValues.Add(this.textBox4.Tag.ToString, this.textBox4.Text.ToString);//city
        BatchRowValues.Add(this.comboBox4.Tag.ToString, ((SimpleState)this.comboBox4.SelectedItem).StateID.ToString);//state
        BatchRowValues.Add(this.comboBox3.Tag.ToString, ((SimpleCountry)this.comboBox3.SelectedItem).getCountryID.ToString);//country
        BatchRowValues.Add(this.textBox5.Tag.ToString, this.textBox5.Text.ToString);


            int _batchRowSequence;

                _batchRowSequence += 1;
                SaveRequestGUID = _helper.BatchSaveRequest(_currentBatchID, BatchRowValues, _batchRowSequence);

               //ClearBatchRow();
               //button4_Click.Enabled = CheckEnableAddRowToBatchButton();


            }

            catch (BatchException ex)
            {
                Interaction.MsgBox(ex.BatchErrorMessage, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation);
           }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Interaction.MessageBox(ex.Message);
                //Interaction.MsgBox(ex.Message);
            }
        return "successfull";
    }
```

button click code:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BBDataOperations obj = new BBDataOperations();
        obj.AddRowToBatch();
        //MessageBox.Show(obj.AddRowToBatch());
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Error 2 'BlackBaudRepository.BBDataOperations' does not contain a definition for 'comboBox1' and no extension method 'comboBox1' accepting a first argument of type 'BlackBaudRepository.BBDataOperations' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\abcfolder\Desktop\BBDemoAlpha.v.3\BBDemoAlpha\BBDemoAlpha\BlackBaudRepository\BBDataOperations.cs 246 37 BlackBaudRepository

Comment: The combobox is a member of the web form, not of the BBDataOperations class. You need to pass a reference to the form or the combobox to the method.